# parameter function in jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to make function with parameter. i working with below code but it is not working. can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function hide(fn){
            $(fn).click(function(){
                $('div').hide()
            })
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        div { width:500px; height:500px; background:#FF0000; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="hide(this)">click for hide</button>
    <a href="#">click</a>
    <button>click</button>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What item do you want to be able to click on to hide the divs? `fn` is not an item.

Comment: i have two or can have more button in html and i dont wana give them id or class that why i want to use parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing: you should write [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), as it is considered best practice. With it, you can maintain a separation of content from code. Thus, the first step is to remove that `onclick` handler on the `<button>` element.

I'm assuming you want to click the button that says "click for hide" to hide the `<div>`. Okay, so let's get some skeleton code out into the `<script>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(<button>).click(function() {
        $(<div>).hide();
    });
});
```

But we need to somehow link that `click` handler to that button, and link that `hide` function to the actual `div`. Here's the easiest way to do this: give your `<button>` and `<div>` some ids. Let's say...

```
<button id="hide-button">...</button>
<div id="hide-div">...</div>
```

Now, we simply need to make a few modifications to our skeleton code:

```
$("#hide-button").click(function() {
    $("#hide-div").hide();
});
```

Here's what this simple code does. When your DOM loads, a nameless function (you can't name functions that you define on the fly*) is invoked from the document's ready event. This nameless function attaches the `click` handler to your `#hide-button` button, so that when you click the button, another anonymous function is invoked. That function calls `hide`, which does some jQuery magic that works in all browsers, on that `#hide-div` div to hide it.

*Well, you can, but only if you define them first and then pass them. Like this:

```
var fn = function() {...};
$(document).ready(fn);
```

**Edit**

Since the asker does not want to use IDs or classes, here's an alternative solution:

```
<script>
    function hide() {
        $('div').hide();
    }
</script>
...
<button onclick="hide()">click for hide</button>
<div></div>
```

Be careful not to place `function hide()` within jQuery's document-ready idiom. Doing so will deny you access to `hide()` because of scoping.

Comment: actually i have two button in html and i dont wana give them id or class that why i want to use parameter. like <button onclick="hide(this)">

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently does nothing more than *set* the click handler when you click on the button.

If you want to continue to use the `onclick` handler on the `button` element, then change your `hide` function to simply `$('div').hide()` (without the `$(fn).click` part). If you'd rather use the `click` function to set the handler, then remove the `onclick` attribute from the `button` element, and in the function at the top change `$(fn).click` to `$('#button').click`, after giving your button an id of `button`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the compact jQuery `ready()` function with something else, so I'd use the readable `$(document).ready()` syntax instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('div').hide()
    })
})
```

And change your HTML a little:

```
<button class="hide">click for hide</button>
```

Instead of binding the function to the element, bind the event handler to the elements with a class of `hide`. When they are clicked, search for the closest `<div>` element and hide it.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, jQuery is slower with classes (like `.hide`) because it needs to find all elements under a certain class and add handlers to them. Use classes if you plan on being able to click multiple buttons to hide something. On the other hand, IDs are faster because they are only allowed to refer to one element (though browsers are generally lenient about this).

Comment: To put it in perspective, can you note what time scale you're talking about here?

Comment: If we're talking about a single instance of a button, there is indeed very little difference in time. The difference is more noticeable when [using many instances of jQuery class selectors](http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2); of course, you won't run into this problem unless you're making complex web apps.